# ssh key validation not working/ ssh: connect to host *** port 22: Connection refused

Tags: ssh

I am following a relatively short and simple guide on this (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2)

Step One—Create the RSA Key Pair

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

"Your public key has been saved in /Users/justinobrien/.ssh/id_rsa.pub." Okay. I renamed the public and private keys 'justin' and 'justin.pub' (as I have to do this for the root user too).

Step Three—Copy the Public Key:
You can paste in the keys using ssh:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh demo@198.51.100.0 "mkdir -p ~/.ssh && chmod 700 ~/.ssh && cat >>  ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

I replaced the ip with my ip, the name of my files and the name of my user('justin') so:

```
cat ~/.ssh/justin.pub | ssh justin@42.93..***"mkdir -p ~/.ssh && chmod 700 ~/.ssh && cat >>  ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

"You may see something like:"

```
The authenticity of host '198.51.100.0 (198.51.100.0)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is b1:2d:33:67:ce:35:4d:5f:f3:a8:cd:c0:c4:48:86:12.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '198.51.100.0' (RSA) to the list of known hosts. 
user@198.51.100.0's password:
```

But this is not what I see, I enter the command above and only get asked to login with my password? I.e. all I see is: `justin@142.93.184.125's password:`

Update, in the comments below I found I may have already set this up and just need to restart the server: I ran `sudo reboot`. Now I can attempt to connect again as either 'root' or 'justin' 3 times, before being asked for the password :

```
ssh justin@142.93..***
ssh: connect to host 142.93..*** port 22: Operation timed out

ssh justin@142.93..***
ssh: connect to host 142.93..*** port 22: Connection refused

ssh justin@142.93..***
ssh: connect to host 142.93..*** port 22: Connection refused
```

If I try again a 4th time, it will ask for my password and allow me to connect. Not really sure what is going on here. I ran `sudo ufw allow 22` to no avail. Thanks for any help.

Comment: @user535733 so do you think I can disable password validation and it will work? I am not sure why it is asking for my password if it is supposed to be authenticating via keys

Comment: @user535733 actually I think I can try and connect via sftp to confirm if this is working

Comment: I now run `ssh justin @142.93.184.125` and it loads for a long time(about 30 seconds) then says `ssh: connect to host justin port 22: Operation timed out`

Comment: trying sudo ufw allow 22/tcp

Comment: actually going to alter the question because now a new issue is popping up

Comment: Remember to delete your old (no longer relevant) comments.

Comment: If you haven't already set up key-based access, then you will need to authenticate once via password *in order to copy the key to the remote server*. Otherwise *anyone* could access your server and copy their keys there.

Comment: @steeldriver it's asked me to validate by password multiple times

Comment: @steeldriver Do I need to have this kind of validation set up? This is my first deployment, by no means building the next fb and I don't think anyone is going to try and hack it. But once I tried to connect via ftp I learned you need to connect via sftp and to do that... you need these keys, no?

Comment: Sorry - I didn't see your update. If you are getting multiple timeouts followed by a successful connection, that sounds more like a network issue (such as a bad routing table entry or conflicting LAN IP address) than anything related to SSH specifically

Comment: I am just going to discard this server and try again lol. Thanks for your repsonse @steeldriver. With that said, the process of deployment and the process of developing the site seem like two totally different skills. I have a solid grasp on django, I don't understand this process at all. Can you tell me what I need to research to better understand this process? So far I'm blindly following youtube videos/digitial ocean articles.

Comment: I agree this sounds like multiple hosts responding to the same IP address. Once that's resolved, if you are still having issues, try `ssh -vv` to see verbose messages about what's happening. I have found bad file permissions are a frequent culprit in these sorts of problems. `ssh -vv` will alert you to such.

Comment: @CupcakeProtocol wow this had quite a bit of output, the ouput I found related to the public/private keys is as follows:

Comment: @CupcakeProtocol actually even that is about 1000 characters too long to copy here. anything in particular I should be looking for?

Comment: @CupcakeProtocol Actually I do see debug1: `Trying private key: /Users/justinobrien/.ssh/id_dsa` but this is not what I named the file. 'root' and 'justin' each have a public and private key named 'root' and 'justin', respectfully. It appears it is looking for a file named id_dsa that does not exist.

Comment: It usually looks for the ancient ssl v1 keys first. Trying keys that don't exist, just in case they do exist, is part of the process. Look for the name of the key you created in the output: `Offering public key: ...` or the like. One thing I have seen is some servers have low caps on number of keys offered. If the right key isn't tried early enough, it can be blocked. Then `Authentications that can continue` will stop listing publickey.

Comment: Oh, and if your newly created key is not listed at all, that's a problem too.